# how to upload images in asp.net core and display them in browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, image, asp.net-core, upload

This is my following attempt. I am unable to upload pic in database using ASP.net Core 6.
Controller.cs

```
         [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(TbUser tbUser, UserRoleViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var selectedRole = model.RoleId;


                //string stringFileName = UploadFile(model);

                string wwrootpath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(model.fileName.FileName);
                string filenameWithExt = Path.GetExtension(model.fileName.FileName);
                filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + filenameWithExt;
                model.fileName = filename;

                string path = Path.Combine(wwrootpath + "uploadfiles", filename);
                using (var filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    model.fileName.CopyTo(filestream);
                }
                _context.TbUsers.Add(tbUser);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

ViewModel.cs

```
        public string? UserPicture { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? fileName { get; set;  }
```

model.cs

```
 public string? UserPicture { get; set; }
```

html.cstml

```
<form asp-action="Create" method="post" >
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserPicture" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserPicture" class="form-control" type="file"  />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserPicture" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
</form>
```

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type string to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile
@

```
model.fileName = filename;
```

database Entity: User_Picture => varchar(50)

Comment: fileName is IFormFile type...  you should bind that to the form.  So <input asp-for="fileName" .... or <input name="fileName" id="fileName" type="file" />  instead of input asp-for="UserPicture" ....  you don't need that in your model as you can create the destination folder in your .cs file... just build the string before you copy fileName (the file in the form):     string fullPath = Path.Combine(DesiredPath, cleanedFilename); using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {

                        fileName.CopyTo(stream);
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes indicates you were tring to copy the tempfile to wwwroot,if you just want to update the file to db and show the pic from db,you could   create another endpoint that return the file content and try as below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ViewModel viewModel)
        {

            ............
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await viewModel.file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                // check the size of the file
                if (memoryStream.Length < 2097152)
                {
                    var file = new AppFile()
                    {
                        Id = someid,
                        Content = memoryStream.ToArray()
                    };

                    _context.AppFile.Add(file);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    var viewmodel = new ViewModel() { UserPicture = "/Home/FileEndpoint?id=" + file.Id.ToString() };
                    return View(viewmodel);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "The file is too large.");
                }
            }
            return BadRequest();
           
        }


 public FileResult FileEndpoint(int Id)
        {
            var content=_context.AppFile.FirstOrDefault (x=>x.Id == Id).Content;
            return File(content, "image/png");
        }
```

Models:

```
public class AppFile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string? UserPicture { get; set; }

        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    }
```

Upload View:

```
@model ViewModel

<form action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   
    <img src=@(Model.UserPicture==null?null:Model.UserPicture) />
    <input asp-for="file" type="file" >


    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

The result:
[image]
You could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0) related

Answer (score 1):

1- You need to add EncType="multipart/form-data"  attribute to form tag so that uploading the file works fine.

2- Could you please provide the raw html code generated and rendered in browser, please?

3- Why are you receiving "TbUser tbUser" from client (as parameter)?

Comment: Actually this is my model class and its object. rest of code I did not share. Apologies.